# I keep getting a syntax error on exception

Tags: python, syntax, error-handling, syntax-error

```
main():
try:
    weight1 = int(input("Enter the weight of package one: "))
    weight2 = int(input("Enter the weight of package two: "))
    if weight1 or weight2 <= 0:
        raise ValueError('Invalid weight')
    price1 = float(input("Enter the price for package one: "))
    price2 = float(input("Enter the price for package one: "))
    math1 = weight1 / price1
    math2 = weight2 / price2
    if math1 < math2:
        print("Package 1 has two has the better price")
    else:
        print("Package 2 has the better price price")
    except ValueError as excpt:
        print(excpt)
        print('Please provide a valid weight. \n')
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print('Invalid price entered.')

main()
```

I'm wondering why do I keep getting a syntax error from this. It looks fine but I keep getting an error

Comment: Your code is incorrectly formatted as shown. In addition to missing the `def`, you also have indentation errors in `try-except`. Not sure if this is caused by pasting.

Comment: A `try` requires an `except` or `finally` on the same indentation level.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `def` before the `main():` definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():

  try:
      weight1 = int(input("Enter the weight of package one: "))
      weight2 = int(input("Enter the weight of package two: "))
      if weight1 or weight2 <= 0:
          raise ValueError('Invalid weight')
      price1 = float(input("Enter the price for package one: "))
      price2 = float(input("Enter the price for package one: "))
      math1 = weight1 / price1
      math2 = weight2 / price2
      if math1 < math2:
          print("Package 1 has two has the better price")
      else:
          print("Package 2 has the better price price")
  except ValueError as excpt:
    print(excpt)
    print('Please provide a valid weight. \n')
  except ZeroDivisionError:
    print('Invalid price entered.')


main()
```

---

```
1. Missing def before main().
2. improper Indentation.
```

Comment: also the `if` statement is gonna be true if `weight1` is nonzero.